# Unbalance of load inflow during redis failure recovery

Tags: redis, haproxy

First of all, English is not my mother tongue, so I hope you understand even if it is strange.

My system uses a dot-net core web server.
I use redis
Write/read distribution as haphroxy
I built a failure recovery system with sentinel.

From dotnet core web server
Write with redis master and read variance with slave are applied.

However, during the failure test, the write/read variance is directed only to the changed master.

If you turn off the write/read distribution, work with only the master to put the load, and perform a failure test, the load is well put into the changed master.

Monitoring is looking at Instantaneous_ops_per_sec on zabbix.

In summary, during the failover test for redis using haphroxy,

1. With write/read distribution, load is concentrated only on the master.
2. If you turn off the write/read variance, of course the load is concentrated only on the master.

I think in the case of 1, there should be a reading load on slave redis, but I'm thinking about it now because it's not.

If you have this experience, please share it.

I can't search even if I try googling.

Programs and associated libraries

- - dotnet core 3.1
    lib -> StackExchange.Redis.Extensions 5.5.0
- - haproxy 2.1.7
- - Redis 5.0.7